Were the fauns ever included in rituals and practices?
The god Faunus  himself, I believe, has a more clearly attested cult. But what about his diminutives - the fauni? Were they ever thought to grant any boons? Virgil seems to call them out in his georgics, along with several fertility and growth gods, so perhaps?
